# How to unit test nested promises with jasmine js?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, parse-server, jasmine-node

I am writing some Parse server cloud functions and trying to understand how I ll write a unit test that involve nested promises. e.g

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myfunction", function(request){
   const common = require('./common')(Parse);

   return common.firstPromise
    .then(function(firstValue){
      return common.secondPromise(firstValue, request.parama.p1);
    })
   .then(function(secondValue){
      return common.thirdPromise(secondValue, request.param.p2);
    })
   .then(function(thirdValue){
       return Parse.run("anotherFunction",{thirdValue:thirdValue});
    })
    .catch(function(e){
       //log
       return Promise.reject(e)
    });
});
```

I am using a setup similar to [like this](https://www.back4app.com/docs/guest/parse-cloud-code-testing). What are my options to make sure each nested promised called/not called with parameters etc. Is that  testable ? or do I need to refactor and deal with each function in the promise chain ?